# Улучшения чата

Tags: php

Есть чат, что можно ему добавить? Заранее спасибо!

Сам чат:

```
<iframe name='chatWindow' id='chatWindow' src ="iframe.php" width="1265" height="400"></iframe>   
<form action="iframe.php" method="post" id="form" target='chatWindow' >
<p>Сообщение:<input name="message" type="text" size="75" maxleght="255">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="OK">
```

А это iframe:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout("window.location.reload()",15000); // Обновление раз в 15 секунд
</script>
```

и

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
      $message = $_POST['message'];
  }

  $db = mysql_connect("...", "...", "...");
  mysql_select_db("...", $db);
  if (trim($message) != "") {
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages (message) VALUES ('$message')");
  }

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages");

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<br>";
      echo "{$row['message']}";
  }
?>
```

И скрипт к чату:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $("#form").onsubmit(function (event) {
            var message = $("input[name='message']", form).value()
            if (message) {
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
        $("#form input[name='message']").bind('change keydown keypress', function (event) {
            var text = $(this).value().replace(/^\s+/, "").replace(/\s+$/, "");
            $("#form input[type='submit']").prop("disabled", text == "");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Где-то я этот скрипт видел, не?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поиграем в предсказателя:
1) Смайлики (Вопрос Влада: как добавить смайлики в чат?!!!php, mysql)
2) Функции модераторов и рейтинга (Вопрос Влада: Как добавить модератора в чат?php,mysql)
3) Комнаты, личный дизайн (Вопрос Влада: Как разделить шаблоны пользователей и сделать безопасный редактор тем?php,mysql, html, css)

Answer (score 2):

Первым вашим (и очень скорым!) ходом должна быть смена пароля на БД. Вот вывод вашего кода

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages");

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<br>";
      echo "{$row['message']}";
  }

Круто
Круто
В скором времени будут сделаны бои!
```

Серьезно, кто-нибудь с достаточным количеством очков, отредактируйте его вопрос, неизвестно, когда Влад появится здесь (мне чуть-чуть не хватает).

Comment: Отредактировать особого смысла нет, здесь ревизии хранятся :)
Так что пусть уже меняет сам поскорее.

С другой стороны — да кому оно надо %)

Comment: Вы все злые=)