# Как сделать поле комментариев в HTML?

Tags: html, php

Скрипт для комментирования на странице.

Comment: Объясните, что значит - поле комментариев.... я, если честно, не понял, что вам надо. Скрипт для комментирования на странице какой-то статьи или просто поле textarea.

Comment: Ждите полную реализцию html 5, там можно будет :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Довольно сложная система, сложнее, чем [чат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/32374/%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0), хотя имеет с ним много общего. Попробуйте освоить сначала приведенный пример. 
Далее, вам потребуется хранить уже не только имя пользователя и сообщение, но так же индекс/адрес страницы, на которой шло комментирование, чтобы каждой странице соответствовали только ее комментарии.

**СТЁБ:**
Ах, да.. Есть еще один вариает:

```
<a href="mailto:YOUR-E-MAIL@MAILPROVIDER.ru">напишите мне письмо!</a>
```

Чистый html. Но комменты придется размещать ручками, да и спаммеры будут докучать.

Comment: Это стеб, или я чего то не понял?)

Comment: После слов "Ах, да..", в общем, стеб. До них - довольно-таки обоснованный ответ. Чат - это частный случай комментирования.

Answer (score 0):

В хтмл никак. Вам нужно на php скрипт делать, привязывая комментарии к страницам или по ИД страниц или по адресам страниц.